# Snap Store does not show categories [Ubuntu 20.04]

Tags: snap, 20.04

I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 and when I open Snap Store it does not show Categories of apps nor all the installed apps in the distro (reinstalling the snap store did not correct the issue).

Below is an attached image of the start screen and the errors during launching of the app.

[image]

```
19:54:45:0907 Gs  failed to create an app for */*/*/*/system/*
19:54:45:0912 Gs  updates-shell: failed to get updates: no plugin could handle get-updates
19:54:45:0913 Gs  failed to create an app for */*/*/*/system/*
19:54:45:0913 Gs  failed to get system app
19:54:45:0914 Gs  Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
19:54:46:0728 Gs  hiding category graphics featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
19:54:46:0762 Gs  not GsPlugin error snapd-error-quark:10: cannot sections: got unexpected HTTP status code 403 via GET to "https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/sections"
19:54:46:0762 Gs  failed to get categories: no categories to show
19:54:46:0763 Gs  not handling error failed for action get-categories: cannot sections: got unexpected HTTP status code 403 via GET to "https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/sections"
19:54:46:0768 Gs  hiding category games featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
19:54:46:0888 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
19:54:47:0068 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
19:54:47:0139 Gs  not GsPlugin error g-io-error-quark:35: Invalid string value converting to GVariant
19:54:47:0142 Gs  not handling error failed for action refine: Invalid string value converting to GVariant
19:54:47:0180 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
19:54:47:0544 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
19:54:48:0020 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
19:54:48:0615 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
bart@zarathustra-ubuntu:~$ snap-store > temp.txt
20:06:18:0890 Gs  failed to create an app for */*/*/*/system/*
20:06:18:0894 Gs  updates-shell: failed to get updates: no plugin could handle get-updates
20:06:18:0895 Gs  failed to create an app for */*/*/*/system/*
20:06:18:0895 Gs  failed to get system app
20:06:18:0896 Gs  Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
20:06:19:0772 Gs  hiding category games featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
20:06:19:0774 Gs  not GsPlugin error snapd-error-quark:10: cannot sections: got unexpected HTTP status code 403 via GET to "https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/sections"
20:06:19:0775 Gs  not handling error failed for action get-categories: cannot sections: got unexpected HTTP status code 403 via GET to "https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/sections"
20:06:19:0775 Gs  failed to get categories: no categories to show
20:06:19:0797 Gs  hiding category graphics featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
20:06:19:0919 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
20:06:20:0036 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
20:06:20:0152 GLib g_variant_new_variant: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
20:06:20:0152 GLib g_variant_new_variant: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
20:06:20:0154 Gs  not GsPlugin error g-io-error-quark:35: Invalid string value converting to GVariant
20:06:20:0154 Gs  not handling error failed for action refine: Invalid string value converting to GVariant
20:06:21:0116 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
20:06:21:0355 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
20:06:21:0626 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
20:06:21:0904 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
```

Comment: I had the same issue but as of this writing the Snap Store has returned to normal operation.  It takes up to 30 seconds for each Category to populate with Snaps but the functionality has returned.

Comment: @sc608 Indeed today the categories show up but none of them has apps inside no matter how long I wait. Also, the errors I posted remain the same.

Comment: The problem seems to have been resolved at last...categories and apps within them are shown even though some seconds are required each time to load all apps.

Answer (score 3):

If this is the first time you open the Ubuntu Software (snap-store) it may need to index and load the apps. Just leave it open for sometime.

Sometimes refreshing the snaps can help

```
sudo snap refresh snap-store
```

If it didn't you may need to reinstall the snap-store

```
sudo snap remove snap-store && sudo snap install snap-store
```

Comment: This worked for me on Ubnutu 22.04.03 LTS that was a fresh install (not an upgrade). 
I wonder if we can force it to reset cache without reinstalling the app.
Edit: found this online but haven't tried it `sudo sh -c 'rm -rf /var/lib/snapd/cache/*'`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. When I went to the snap store categories they were blank. I had to click on a category and leave it open for about 30-45 seconds then it populated for me. Tedious but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Lol:)

https://status.snapcraft.io/

4 days ago offline (not work)

- Snap downloads (default)
- api.snapcraft.io - search
- api.snapcraft.io - refresh

**Not the best solutions!**