# Snap store dont't show categories on focal

Tags: snap

I've search on the web and found some answers but didnt worked, there was a question but it was only answered with the snap online status, wich is supposed to be okay now.

When I opened the snap-store ,it couldnt find the store it was pointing to a 4.15 version, I switched the link to the 4.54 version and the store opened, but the categories is[empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emdaz.jpg)

I had restarted the store, refresh the snap-store, restarted the pc and the problem lingers :c

Comment: The issue still is present and there's no info about it :T

Comment: I think you may find the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1230956/1091060)